# How fast can you determine if vectors are linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let us suppose you have $m$ real-valued vectors of length $n$ where $n \geq m$.

How fast can you determine if they are linearly independent?

In the case where $m = n$ one way to determine independence would be to compute the determinant of the matrix whose rows are the vectors. I tried some googling and found that [the best known algorithm to compute the determinant of a square matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations) with $n$ rows runs in $O \left ( n^{2.373} \right )$. That puts an upper bound on the case where $m = n$. But computing the determinant seems like an overkill. Furthermore it does not solve the case where $n > m$.

Is there a better algorithm? What is the known theoretical lower bound on the complexity of such an algorithm?

Comment: Obviously Gaussian elimination does it in $O(m^2n)$; I suppose you are interested only in results better than that?

Comment: Yes, I wonder if there is something faster.

Answer (score 4):

Forming a matrix $A$, this problem is equivalent to determining whether $Ax = 0$ has nontrivial solutions. Solving a linear system can be decomposed into a series of matrix multiplications, so it will always have the complexity of the fastest matrix multiplication algorithm.

Comment: A series op operations of length bounded independently of the size of the matrix?

Comment: Yes, that is one way to approach the problem. But I do not need the solution of the equation you propose, I just need to know whether or not it has a solution.

Comment: The number of said multiplications only scales as $\log{N}$, where $N$ is the length of the matrix; the general strategy is to solve a series of subproblems formed by dividing the matrix into successive powers of $2$.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik, I'm not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: You provided one solution to the problem. I do not doubt that it is correct. But I am interested in the solution with the smallest known computational complexity.

Comment: I would be extremely surprised if it were possible to calculate the rank of a matrix faster than one could solve the associated linear system.

Answer (score 1):

Like Christopher A. Wong said this comes down to solving $Ax=0$ and checking for a nontrivial solution. There are a few approaches to doing this in the case $n>m$. One way would be to solve by finding the LU decomposition of $A$ and then using forward and backward substitution. This can be accomplished in $O(\frac{2}{3}n^3)$ floating point operations. You could also find the QR decomposition of $A$. Then the rank of $A$ will be the same as the rank of $R$. Since $R$ is triangular it is easy to see it's rank. This can be accomplished in $O(n^3)$ floating point operations. There are many ways to implement the QR decomposition. If you are going to do it I suggest using the Householder transformation approach, it is the most numerically stable. A good place to read about this stuff is Fundamentals of Matrix Computations by Watkins.

Comment: Since $O(n^3)$ is worse than $O(m^2n)$, I gather from the reply to my comment under the question that these ideas are not good enough to interest OP.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following steps

1. Arrange the vectors in form of a matrix with each vector representing a column of matrix.
2. Vectors of a matrix ***are always Linearly Dependent*** if number of columns is greater than number of rows (where ***m > n***).
3. Vectors of a matrix having number of rows greater than or equal to number of columns (where ***n >= m***) are ***Linearly Independent*** only if Elementry Row Operations on Matrix can convert it into a Matrix containing only ***Mutually Orthogonal Identitity Vectors*** (An ***Identity Vector*** is a Vector having 1 as one of the component and 0 as other components). Otherwise the vectors are ***Linearly Dependent***

So, the only thing that is required is a fast algorithm to do elementry row operations on a matrix with ***n>=m*** to check whether the vectors in it can be converted to ***Mutually Orthogonal Identitity Vectors***

If someone thinks this answer is wrong, please prove it by giving some counter  examples of Matrices.